# Refreshing Panel of Images with Button Event-Handler

Tags: java, swing, event-handling

I'm trying to refresh a panel of Icons with a "Refresh" button, but can't figure out what to put in the event handler to perform this task.  I just have the code to perform the task once (below).  Can someone help me with this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class FourRandomCards extends JFrame {
    JButton jbtRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    CardsPanel cardsPanel = new CardsPanel();

    public FourRandomCards() {
    add(cardsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jbtRefresh, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//=============================================================
        /** can't figure out what to put in event-handler **/
        jbtRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            }
        });
//=============================================================
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new FourRandomCards();
        frame.setTitle("Four Random Cards");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class CardsPanel extends JPanel {
        public CardsPanel() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int card = (int)(Math.random() * 54 + 1);
                ImageIcon cardIcon = new ImageIcon
                ("image/card/" + card + ".png");
                JLabel jlblCard = new JLabel(cardIcon);

                add(jlblCard);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you want to remove all the current labels and reload them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to remove all the existing components and re-add them.  This would suggest you would require some method capable of fulfilling this requirement.

Because you're using local variables, you won't be able access the `cardsPanel` variable unless you make it `final` or use class instance variables...

```
public class FourRandomCards extends JFrame {
    JButton jbtRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    final CardsPanel cardsPanel = new CardsPanel();

    public FourRandomCards() {
    add(cardsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(jbtRefresh, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//=============================================================
        /** can't figure out what to put in event-handler **/
        jbtRefresh.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardsPanel.refresh();
            }
        });
//=============================================================
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new FourRandomCards();
        frame.setTitle("Four Random Cards");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class CardsPanel extends JPanel {
        public CardsPanel() {
            refresh();
        }

        public void refresh() {
            removeAll();
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                int card = (int)(Math.random() * 54 + 1);
                ImageIcon cardIcon = new ImageIcon
                ("image/card/" + card + ".png");
                JLabel jlblCard = new JLabel(cardIcon);

                add(jlblCard);
            }
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```